# Casbah - check if string is parseable as ObjectId

Tags: scala, casbah

Is there a simple built in way to check if a string is a valid ObjectId? I know if I try to construct an ObjectId from an invalid string it throws an exception, is there a way to circumvent the try-catch block?

One possible way would be to check against this regex: `^[0-9a-b]{48}$`
Is there something more elegant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is method `ObjectId.isValid(String s)`: [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html)

Comment: I thought that maybe Casbah somewhere had a method that would yield an Option[ObjectId] but it seems that I will have to implement it.